# How to determine TimeDateStamp

Tags: c, windows

I was coding something about windows PE header. I want determine Timestamp value. 
This is _IMAGE_FILE_HEADER structure

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_FILE_HEADER {
    WORD    Machine;
    WORD    NumberOfSections;
    DWORD   TimeDateStamp;
    DWORD   PointerToSymbolTable;
    DWORD   NumberOfSymbols;
    WORD    SizeOfOptionalHeader;
    WORD    Characteristics;
} IMAGE_FILE_HEADER, *PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER;
```

Value of this variable is TimeDateStamp: 0x58e451ac

Comment: First google hit searching for "_IMAGE_FILE_HEADER ": [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The docs say it is the low 32 bits of the timestamp, which is the number of seconds since midnight (00:00:00) on January 1, 1970, universal time. It will wrap around to 0 at 2106-02-07T06:28:16+00:00.

Comment: The TimeDateStamp 0x58e451ac corresponds to 2017-04-05T02:08:44+00:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution like that.

```
 time_t TimeX = (time_t)header.TimeDateStamp;
 tm* pGMT = gmtime(&TimeX);
 char* pTime = asctime(pGMT);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN: IMAGE_FILE_HEADER structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313(v=vs.85).aspx), the `TimeDateStamp` member of `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER` is the low 32 bits of the time stamp of the image. It represents the time that the image was created by the linker. The value is represented as the number of seconds since the start of January 1, 1970 in Universal Coordinated Time.

It could be converted to a `FILETIME` value using the following function:

```
FILETIME TimeDateStampToFileTime(DWORD timeDateStamp)
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER ftu;
    FILETIME ft;

    ftu.QuadPart = (timeDateStamp + 11644473600ull) * 100000000ull;
    ft.LowPart = ftu.u.LowPart;
    ft.HighPart = ftu.u.Highpart;
    return ft;
}
```

Then you can convert the `FILETIME` to a broken-down `SYSTEMTIME` structure using the Windows `FileTimeToSystemTime` function.

Comment: I got the multiplication and addition the wrong way round in `TimeDateStampToFileTime()`. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score -1):

```
It's very easy to do in BASIC:
Dim ConvertedTimeStamp As Double, DateStg As String
'divide TimeDateStamp by # of seconds in a day,
'then add date value for Jan 1st, 1970
ConvertedTimeStamp = (TimeDateStamp / 86400) + #1/1/1970#
'convert result to readable string
DateStg = Format(ConvertedTimeStamp, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.